# Visual Studio 2015 Community - Debugger Acting Strange

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Either I'm missing something beyond obvious here, or something has gone seriously wrong with my development environment under the debugger.

Here's the first call, with the value for the parameter shown:

[image: We have a value here]

And then, when stepping into the method, the next line on the call stack, I am seeing:

[image: Not here!]

I have cleaned the solution, rebuilt everything with no errors, restarted Visual Studio, rebooted, and it is still acting like this.

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you by any chance debugging while the 'Solution configuration' is set to `Release`? I haven't seen this specific error, but I have experienced other weird behaviour while debugging in VS2015 with the config set to `Release`. Changing the setting to `Debug` fixed the problem for me.

Comment: @LarsKristensen that is likely what's going on, but there's more nuance to it: the name of the configuration isn't the culprit, rather the fact that optimization is on (which, usually but not always, happens to be the case in release builds). With heavy optimizations, the assembly diverts so far from the original source code that the debugger cannot possibly get values for all variables. For example, because the optimizer decided to get rid of the variable all together and only use a temprorary placeholder somewhere.

Comment: @stijn You are right, I should have mentioned that `Release` and `Debug` are just labels for the underlying settings. You could also create your own setting, using the `Release` setting as a template, but without optimization, so that it would allow debugging to work properly.

Comment: @LarsKristensen Ding ding ding, we have a winner!  I was actually running this in our custom "staging" build configuration accidentally, and this new assembly was added to that build configuration to build in Release, while the rest were in Debug.  Thanks!

Comment: Great, glad you fixed it :-) Credit goes to @stijn for explaining what is actually causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was due to the assembly being called being in Release mode while the calling assembly was in Debug.

We had a custom build configuration called "Staging" which is what I was running in Visual Studio.  Every assembly was in "Debug" in this configuration except for that particular one which was being called.